# jQuery - How dynamically change the value?

Tags: jquery

I have in my html code:

```
<input class="hidd" type="radio" name="org1" value="1" />
<input class="hidd" type="radio" name="org1" value="2" />
<input class="hidd" type="radio" name="org1" value="3" />

<input type="hidden" id="crc" name="crc" value="20120109|0" />
```

I want to jQuery detect which item was selected by user and then set the value according to the formula:
if radiobutton with value "1" is selected by user then input value of id="crc" should be: "20120109|1" instead of "20120109|0". So in other words - keep all numbers before sign "|" and change only value behind this sign "|". How can I do that? Maybe take value from id="crc", delete last number and add new number? Or maybe in another way?

```
$('.hidd').click(function () {

});
```

Comment: Why on earth do you need to do this? Just have two hidden `input` elements, `crc_date` and `crc_choice`.

Comment: and after your wrote the `.click()` method you stopped trying?

Comment: To select the element whose id=`"crc"`, you can use `$('#crc')`

Comment: I don't think, it is wrong question. I would rather upvote it..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.hidd').click(function () {
    var crc = $("#crc").val().split("|");
    $("#crc").val(crc[0] + "|" + $(this).val());
});
```

Or to cover all possible methods of selecting an option:

```
$('.hidd').change(function () {
    var crc = $("#crc").val().split("|");
    $("#crc").val(crc[0] + "|" + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Just one notice though: `click` will be fired only if the element is clicked (unless will be fired artificially by different script), so the better idea is to use `change` instead of `click`. As the name suggests, it will be fired when the value is changed, so OP's requirement ("_item was selected by user_") should be met then :)

Comment: Thanks for help. I knew only command "explode" for php, now I know how to use "split" in jQuery. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.hidd').click(function () {
    var v = $('#crc').val().split('|');
    $('#crc').val(v[0] + '|' + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: This will react only on clicks, so changes made in a different way (eg. by keyboard or using touch-enabled devices that may not fire `click` event) will not trigger the code OP needs.

Comment: True, but it looks like it is hidden anyway `class="hidd"` so there is no touch or keyboard access.

Comment: @PiTheNumber, the element holding the result is the hidden one, not the radio buttons that receive the `click` / `change` event..

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `val()` method, string's `split()` method and you will get something like:

```
var crc = $('#crc');
var radio = $(':radio[name="org1"]');
crc.val(crc.val().split('|')[0] + '|' + radio.val());
```

If you want this to be triggered when the value of the radio button is changed, then do the following (jQuery 1.7+):

```
$(':radio[name="org1"]').on('change', function(){
    var crc = $('#crc');
    crc.val(crc.val().split('|')[0] + '|' + $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
$('.hidd').change(function () {
  var crc = $('#crc');
  var value = crc.val();
  crc.val( value.split('|')[0] + '|' + this.value );
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/cmCS9/

---

or the regex way

```
$('.hidd').change(function () {
  var crc = $('#crc');
  var value = crc.val();
  crc.val( value.replace(/\d+$/, this.value) );
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/cmCS9/1/

Comment: "The regex way" is nice, although it wouldn't work if he decided to put something other than numbers in the second part.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hidd').click(function () {
   $("#crc").val('20120109|' + $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hidd').click(function () {

     $('#crc').val('20120109|' + $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hidd').click(function () {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#crc").val($("#crc").val().replace("/|[0-9]/","|" + $(this).val()));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regexp

```
   $('.hidd').click(function () {
        var crc = $("#crc"),
            $this = $(this);
        if($this.is(":checked")) {
            crc.val( crc.val().replace("/[0-9]$/", $this.val());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider going beyond jQuery to the awesome power of JavaScript regular expressions:
    "20120109|0".match("[0-9]*\|")
will return "20120109|".

Putting this together with your jQuery and requirements:

```
$('.hidd').change(function () {
    var crc = $("#crc"),
        old = crc.val(),
        num = $(this).val(),
        pfx = old.match("[0-9]*\\|"),
        nvl = pfx + num;
    crc.val(nvl);
    // here you will want to return true or false
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  $('.hidd').change(function () {
    var previousVal=$("input[type='hidden']").val();
    $("input[type='hidden']").val(previousVal+$(this).val());
});
```

Comment: This will append to the existing value, and could end up with `20120109|0|1|2|3`

Comment: Rory, you are person with eagle's eyes :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: At least it will be triggered at the correct moment, not only when clicked ;)